# Is there a way to return more than one row from multiple matches in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to find a way to fill two columns in one table with two rows of data from another table based on matched criteria.

To be more specific, A3:D contains the data I'd like to pull from. I'm trying to find a formula that would:

1. Look for values in A3:A that match the values from $F8.
2. Populate $G5:$H8 with the contents of columns C and D. (The matched row and the next row.)
3. Include additional two rows from columns C and D if there are multiple matches found in A3:A

I'm currently using the following formula `=OFFSET($A$3,match($F8,A:A,0)-3,2,2,2)` which is returning some of the data I need, but only for the first match. If there is another cell in column A that matches $F8, the values from C:D are not returned.

Here is the link to a sample for reference (which includes a "Goal" tab to show what I'm trying to display): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WYy-oSptjKl2YUIES8MML1Hzv39_MOXi55-m4TAJJ-s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `filter()` formula in cells `G5`, `G9` and so on:

`=filter( C$5:D$22, (A$5:A$22 = F8) + (A$4:A$21 = F8) )`

Comment: This is perfect and so much simpler than what I was trying to do! Thank you!